# Why does Fluid open Google links instead of sending them to my default browser?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, fluid.app

I have [Fluid](http://fluidapp.com) apps for Trello and for MSO chat. Trello's URL whitelist consists only of `*trello.com*` and Chat's is similarly limited:

[image]
[image]

Clicking links to any other URL opens the page in Chrome, my default browser. This works perfectly in all cases except with Google documents. Fluid always tries to open Google docs in another tab in its own window, instead of sending it out to my default browser.

I can't figure out where this behavior is coming from. Has anyone else ever experienced it? What's the fix?

Comment: Is there a link that shows this in practice? Perhaps posting a history to chat with a doc or making a test case in a chat room here?

Comment: @bmike All my transcripts are employee-only so I'll find a test case. Stand by!

Comment: You could raffle off something in our chat room? Picture of a rare and likely valuable sticky note doodle of a chaos hire! :)

Comment: @bmike LOL. Didn't see your comment in time, so we're stuck with [a boring mostly-blank google doc](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/13737410#13737410) :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Developer of Fluid Here. Basically, this is a bug.

It stems from the fact that Google is the search provider supported in the toolbar search field. Therefore `google.com` URLs are currently always white-listed.

I would like to fix this eventually.

Comment: So there is nothing we can do in the meantime in white/black -listing to get around this bug?

Do you have an ETA for fixing this? Maybe a link to your issue tracker?